# Why did sourcetree delete my commit?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm learning to use source control via git and sourcetree

My code commits graph had only one branch.

Sourcetree was drawing label "Master" on the most recent commit called "Cells verification"

I added a line of comment to `PlayerDispatcher` file. `//commit undo test`

I commited it like "Commit undo test"

Then I double clicked the previous version (double click is for `checkout`). There appeared a warning saying that a separate HEAD will be created. I din't understand what is wrong with it and clicked OK.

After it the project had two branches. On "Cells verification" there was a label "HEAD". On "Commit undo test" there was a label "Master"

I deleted `SentCell` file and added changes to a `PlayerDispatcher` file.

After it I realized that I need some functionality of deleted `SentCell` back, but in other file.

I commited all changes like "Changed PlayerDispatcher and deleted SentCell".

Then I double-clicked "Cells verification". Now "Cells verification" is labeled head "Commit undo test" is labeled "Master" and "Changed PlayerDispatcher and deleted SentCell" does not exist (`PlayerDispatcher` change are lost).

Graph has only one branch

Why did checkout delete newer file? Is there a way to restore it (I did changes mostly for testing, but I'm still interested in possibility of it)? Is there a way to prevent git from any permanent deletions?

Comment: *I'm learning to use source control via git and **sourcetree*** (my emphasis). There is your mistake, buddy `:)` You should stay away from GUIs, at least until you're comfortable enough with Git using only the command line.

Comment: I was just working on the project and understood that I waste a lot of time before changing something if it involves deletion of classes. Version control GUI seemed the fastest solution

Comment: @Jubobs, actually SourceTree hides very little. It's one of the closest GUIs to the standard command-line stuff.

Comment: @Chris I understand not everyone would agree on that, but that's my opinion.

Comment: You need to fish the commit whose message reads "Changed PlayerDispatcher and deleted SentCell" out of the `HEAD` reflog, but I have no idea how to do that in SourceTree.

Comment: There is `Actions`->`Open in terminal` Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then I double clicked the previous version (double click is for `checkout`). There appeared a warning saying that a separate HEAD will be created. I din't understand what is wrong with it and clicked OK.
>
> After it the project had two branches. On "Cells verification" there was a label "HEAD". On "Commit undo test" there was a label "Master"

It might have looked like you had two branches, but you didn't really. `HEAD` isn't a branch; it's a pointer to what's currently checked out. When you checked `master` out again, `HEAD` moved to the same place as `master`, leaving nothing pointing to your new commit.

Git only shows commits that are *reachable* from a head. Because you didn't create a second branch, Git isn't showing the commit that is there, but it's probably still in your repository.

Try running `git reflog`. This should include something like

```
abcd123 HEAD@{0}: checkout moving from <some long hash> to master
```

If you haven't modified your repository since, this will likely be the first line. If you have modified it, you may have to go down a few lines. In this case, the `HEAD@` number will also be different.

Once you find the right line, copy the hash (probably the first 7 characters or so should be enough) and check it out again:

```
git checkout <hash from reflog>
```

You should find that you've got your commit back. Now, if you want to keep it, create a branch to point to it:

```
git branch <branch-name> <hash from reflog>
```

Comment: This behavior was a surprise to me, even after working with Git for almost a year, and trying to support another user.  It seems to be assumed as natural knowledge, but it isn't and probably should be emphasized at the start of every exchange: ***Git stores the commit tree as a singly linked list.*** ***Branches are just pointers that can be checked out.*** ***If a commit isn't checked out and doesn't have a parent, tag, or branch, it will be "lost".*** Clarity on these points (and we need reminders more than instruction!) makes using Git so much easier.